# How to upload user picture in moodle from other system using web service

Tags: moodle

I have Moodle & Drupal integrated system, Drupal is primary, user is created in drupal first then it will create in moodle via web services, but I am not able to carry user picture from drupal to moodle, I don't want core fixes, need clean and systematically solution for it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't an appropriate web service in core which supports this at the moment. You can see web services documented in your Moodle install in Home ▶ Site administration ▶ Plugins ▶ Web services ▶ API Documentation.

There are many ways to support this with plugins, but since you do not seem keen to go down this route, have your considered using Gravatar as a solution? There are docs on how to set this up: http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Roles_settings#Enable_Gravatar

Answer (score 0):

the first step upload the picture

```
localhost/moodle/webservice/upload.phptoken=9f47591ed3f6cc53720f0dc4e81&filearea=draft
```

Params:-

```
token=9f47591ed3f6cc53720f0dc4e81
filearea=draft
```

then you will get a response like

```
[
{
    "component": "user",
    "contextid": 5,
    "userid": "2",
    "filearea": "draft",
    "filename": "Ali Hasans Resume.pdf",
    "filepath": "/",
    "itemid": 560134043,
    "license": "unknown",
    "author": "Admin User",
    "source": "O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:6:\"source\";s:21:\"Ali Hasans Resume.pdf\";}"
}
```

]

- second step
  update the profile picture

  localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json&draftitemid=560134043&wsfunction=core_user_update_picture&wstoken=9f47591ed3f6cc53720f0dc4e81

params

```
moodlewsrestformat=json
draftitemid=560134043  this "draftitemid" comes from upload.php response
wsfunction=core_user_update_picture
wstoken=9f47591ed3f6cc53720f0dc4e81
```

if it's a success then the response will like

```
{
"success": true,
"profileimageurl": "http://localhost/moodle/theme/image.php/alpha/core/1609845491/u/f1",
"warnings": []
```

}

here I get this idea https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-56070